# Using flex-basis to control the number of items displayed on the line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to push elements out in order to hide them while using flex.

For example, if `flex-basis` is 50%, show only two items flexed into the given space while the other elements are in `overflow:hidden;` territory.

Or if `flex-basis` is 25% then only show 4 flex elements and hide the others.

Is this possible?

```css
.bargraph {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.bargraph>dt {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<dl class="bargraph">
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
</dl>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sffo02dp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `flex-basis`, use the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties to control sizing.

More specifically:

- `flex-grow: 0`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 50%` (or whatever you want it to be)

This tells flex items: *don't grow, don't shrink, be a fixed percentage width*

You can combine all these properties into one rule with the `flex` shorthand property:

```
flex: 0 0 50%;       /* two items will show, OR... */
flex: 0 0 25%        /* four items will show, OR... */
flex: 0 0 20%        /* five items will show */
```

Here's the full code:

```css
.bargraph {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.bargraph>dt {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<dl class="bargraph">
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dt>test</dt>
</dl>
```

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sffo02dp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this in your CSS file

```
bargraph>dt{
 min-width: 10em;
}
```

This should be a good alternative and you can put the value based on the parent width.

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding..