# PHP loop to fill flex-parent with rows

Tags: php, css, loops, foreach, flexbox

I'm currently trying to find a way how to fill flex parent with flex childs. I have data in the database, so i pick those data by foreach loop. The thing is I want to have 4 flex children per row, as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

And I just can't think about any loop which could let me do this.

```
<div class="grid">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $c): ?>
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="grid-pivot"><a href="results.php?searchtype=1&id=<?php echo($a['category_id']) ?>"><?= $c['categoryJmeno'] ?></a></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `display: grid;` = https://jsbin.com/yecaseqiwo/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Or change your loop, https://3v4l.org/Ajfn9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37336930/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a width to those elements via CSS:

```
.grid-pivot {
  width: 25%;
}
```

or maybe a little less (24%) if that doesn't work due to whitespace or similar.

If you want padding, include it and add `box-sizing: border-box`

```
.grid-pivot {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

And if you want margin (like in the image you posted), use `calc` for the width to include it:

```
.grid-pivot {
  width: calc(25% - 60px);
  margin: 30px;
}
```

Comment: How does `.grid-row` fit into this? Wont it cause each item to be on a new line, but with 25% width?